# PostgreSQL has two servers running on port 5432, Mac 10.11

Tags: macos, postgresql

I know that this is a common issue with a lot of resources online but nothing seems to have worked for myself so far. When I try to start the pg server (I downloaded the postgres.app) I always get the same `there is already a PostgreSQL server running on port 5432`. I used the command `sudo lsof -i 5432` and got this as a result:

> COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>
> postgres 69175 badman    5u  IPv6 0xfb574d5e65486297      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
>
> postgres 69175 badman    6u  IPv4 0xfb574d5e68f8fbc7      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)

I have tried installing pg multiple times using homebrew, postgres.app and accidentally installed pg Enterprise when I first got my mac. I don't know if multiple downloads of pg from different sources maybe affecting it, despite me trying to uninstall them. How can I fix this so that I'm only using one, preferably the postgres.app installation (as i'm new to coding and it's what I'm used to). Im using Mac v10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

Find the Process with Port:

```
$ lsof -i :5432
```

Kill the process with Process ID:

```
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

In your case **kill -9 69175**

**Note: Sometimes lsof -i :port will show nothing. try sudo lsof -i :port